# Laplace domain: poles on both sides of the jw and x plane

Tags: signal-processing, signal-integrity, fourier, laplace-transform

For a pole/zero plot, if a system has a pole on the left side only it is stable, and if the pole is on the right only it is not stable, but if the pole is on the right and left, would that be stable? And what determines if the system is causal or not, as far as the pole/zero plot concerns?

Comment: In the S-plane if there is a single pole on the right side it is unstable, it doesn't matter how many poles are on the left.

Comment: thanks @Makoto, so as I understand, even if we have a pole at the center and on the right, it is still unstable? what about causality?

Comment: yes, any pole on the right causes instability. Don't know enough about causality to comment.

Comment: Remember poles on the right side means e^(positive real number), and that grows boundless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system will simply be non-causal.
For a system to be causal, (only exist after t>0), all poles must lie on the left of the jw axis and similarly for anti-causality, they must be on the right. Any system not satisfying these is simply non-causal.

Comment: ok, that makes sense now, but if we have one imaginary and one real pole at different location on the left side and one hole on the right, how do we chose our ROC? I know poles can not be inside a ROC.